# Find volume between two surfaces with double integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

Find the volume interior to $y^2+z^2=2$ and exterior to $x^2-y^2-z^2=2$. I have solved a few exercises of this kind, but all of them had one dependent function of $x$ and $y$ only, but here both of them have $z$ in the equation.

To find the volume using double integrals you must use:
$$V=\iint z\ dA$$
Where $z$ is the inferior base. Also, it could be that the best way to solve the exercise is using polar coordinates, in that case you use $x=ρcos\theta $ and $y=ρsin\theta $

Here's a graph of the functions:

[image]

Comment: Would the point $(x,y,z) = (10^8, 0,0)$ appear in your volume?

Comment: No, that point would be outside the desired volume. I edit the question with a graph of the functions. The point you describe is marked with green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

$$2 \int\limits_{r=0}^{\sqrt{2}} 2 \pi r \sqrt{r^2+2}\ dr = \frac{8}{3} \left(4-\sqrt{2}\right) \pi$$

Use cylindrical shells around the $x$ axis and integrate in just the positive side ($0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{r^2 + 2}$).  Here $r = \sqrt{y^2 + z^2}$.

One shell in red (up to the radius limit, in yellow):

[image]

You *could* use double integrals (over $\theta$ and $r$), but the $\theta$ integral is trivial ($2 \pi$), so I just used that in the above.

$$2 \int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{2 \pi} \int\limits_{r=0}^{\sqrt{2}} r \sqrt{r^2 + 2}\ d\theta\ dr$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is definitely correct. However, I can't quite understand what you did. Is it possible to solve this problem using double integrals? In the case of a negative answer, could you please recommend me a book or page that I can study to better understand this procedure?

Comment: What is the volume of the red (differential) cylinder of radius $r$, length $\sqrt{y^2 + z^2 + 2}$ and thickness $dr$?  So just integrate that for $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: That works, thank you very much for your help. Have a good day